# Add gradient to water on a SVG map like in Google Maps (PHP / JS)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, svg, raphael

Taking a closer look at Google Maps, you will see that the water areas are not just one color but a color gradient. Near the land the blue is darker than further away.

I have an SVG map on a small website about timezones (http://worldtimemap.net/). The map looks rather boring and I thought about adding an water gradient effect like in Google Maps by program code.

Any hint on the programming behind this effect? I already include Raphael JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a drop-shadow filter CSS property to the SVG like so:

```
svg {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
}
```

with whatever adjustments to the blur/spread/color values you want, of course.